# How to replace last 15 digits of a string with x?

Tags: php

Let's say I've got a string which I want to display on my user's settings page. It's the HWID of the specific user but I want to hide like the last 15 characters from the string with `x` for example. How to do this ? Probably `preg_replace()` .. please let me know.

Example string: `aaaec315bbfb9184fd9d7c8e165b297d` but it will display like `aaaec315bbfb9184f**************` for exmaple

I believe it can only contain an alphanumeric characters since it's a HWID.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = substr($string,0,-15)."xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Comment: Oh, I will try it out now. Also, can I use the same `substr()` to remove miliseconds in displaying `getdate()` result from my mssql server 2005 table?

Answer (score 1):

While @hellocde's example does do this, I would just use the native [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) function instead as this is what it's intended for.

```
substr_replace($string, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', -15);
```

Which will produce:

```
aaaec315bbfb9184fdxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

[Functional example](https://eval.in/205511)

Comment: It's greatly appreciated. Before I accept the answer please let me know lastly if I can use `substr()` to remove last miliseconds from `getdate()` result? I've got column where it has dates like: `2014-10-11 22:57:48.501` so can I safely use it to display the date without the `.501` for example? I know it will work but still is it fine to do it? Thanks once again!

Comment: @Monk25 `getdate()` returns an array, so how are you constructing the string from the array? That's probably where the real issue is.

Comment: I am using a stored procedure on MSSQL Server 2005 and it updates the column on my database with value like that: `2014-10-11 22:57:48.501`, so I can use `substr()` to return only the first digits without `.miliseconds` at the end as I stated in my previous comment above. It works but is it good to use it? That's what I mean?